# Find ArrayList positions where specific string appears

Tags: java

Sorry for this very basic question but i'm stuck..
Suppose we have an array

```
{user , client , client ,user, client , user , client , client , client}
```

How can i create a "for" loop ( any other idea is  appreciated...)that returns two variables regarding the positions where "client" String appears continuously ; I mean something like (x=1 , y=2) , (x=4 , y=4) , (x=6 , y=8) Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `x` and what is `y`?

Comment: So for any subarray created only from for example 'client' you want to find begin and end index of such subarrays?

Comment: Some hints : look at the syntax of the `forEach loop`. Look at  `String.equals()`. You cannot return 2 values but you can return an object with has 2 attributes.

Comment: variables reffering to positions

Comment: @AliAmiri Indeed, I seldom need to do something like this for pleasure :) Homework is appropriate on this site if the OP shows what was tried and what fails.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Yes, as you said if OP show us some work, but I dont see any work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is to find pairs of indexes (begin and end), that are seelcting subarrays containing only "client" value. So in such subarray they will be no other values. We can deduct it from your test data.

Test method:

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    String[] input = new String[] { "user", "client", "client", "user", "client", "user", "client", "client",
        "client" };
    for (Integer[] i : doFun(input, "client")) {
      System.out.println("(" + i[0] + "," + i[1] + ")");
    }

  }
```

Function body:

```
  public List<Integer[]> doFun(String[] input, String wantedValue) {
    List<Integer[]> output = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    int beginIndex = -1;
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (!wantedValue.equals(input[i])) {
        if (beginIndex > -1) {
          output.add(new Integer[] { beginIndex, beginIndex + length });
        }
        beginIndex = -1;
        continue;
      }
      if (beginIndex < 0) {
        beginIndex = i;
        length = 0;
      } else {
        length++;
      }
    }

    if (beginIndex > -1) {
      output.add(new Integer[] { beginIndex, beginIndex + length });
    }

    return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i see three problems you have to solve here
1.: iterate over the array with a counter
2.: find the position of the string
3.: return both values from your method

following the divide and conquer approach (solve one problem at a time) should help you